# How to avoid integrity constraint violations from duplicate sql insert commands triggered by >= async api calls at the same time in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, laravel, asynchronous

Our react app triggering X amount of same async requests (with different inputs) to our Laravel GraphQL API to avoid slow performance and improve fault tolerance.

Sometimes they insert into the same intermediate table with the same values, even with checks to see if the value doesn't already exist before inserting.

My guess is that Laravel is allowing N amount of async calls to insert into the intermediate table at the same time after they both bypass the check to see if the record already exists.

Then this throws an Integrity Constraint error due to a duplicate value and errors out.

Other than sending each request sequentially (which we are doing now but is slower) or queueing jobs to perform the inserts (which is more complicated), are there any other ways to make sure that MySQL doesn't run those 2 queries at the same time?

I have read that upserting or using a try catch can mask the error, but still doesn't solve the core problem.

Here is the code that is triggered multiple times and throwing the error.

I rewrote the code to not use `sync` or `syncWithoutDetaching` because they were both throwing the error more frequently.

```
    /**
     * Add strategy_department record, if that key does not already exist
     *
     * @param Strategy $strategy
     * @param Task $task
     *
     */
    private function addStrategyDepartmentIfDoesntExist(Strategy $strategy, Task $task): void
    {
        $this->handleErrorsForAddStrategyDepartmentIfDoesntExist($strategy, $task);
        $strategy_department_table_name = 'strategy_department';

        /**
         * If error is not thrown, then we can add the department to the strategy if it doesn't exist
         */
        $strategy_department_found = DB::table($strategy_department_table_name)
            ->where('strategy_id', $strategy->id)
            ->where('department_id', $task->service->department->id)->first();

        if (!isset($strategy_department_found)) {
            DB::table($strategy_department_table_name)->insert([
                'strategy_id' => $strategy->id,
                'department_id' => $task->service->department->id,
                'created_at' => now(),
                'updated_at' => now(),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can try to use transaction, this is much better approach in your case  https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#manually-using-transactions.

Comment: This would be interesting to read as well https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1441

Comment: the benefit i see with transactions is i can retry if they fail (if needed in other cases), but other than that, if they are running the same transaction at the same time won't it still throw the error? i think the problem is that the error is still thrown

Comment: MySQL transactions provide an effective method for executing multiple statements as a single unit, making it possible to safely modify data, while preventing concurrent users from updating the same data or overwriting changed data. If any statements within a transaction fail or do not achieve their desired results, the changes can be rolled back and the database returned to its original state, as it existed prior to starting the transaction. Otherwise, MySQL commits the changes to the database and then terminates the transaction.

Comment: In this case you can store error and the failed submit to the separate table to be able to see what's wrong

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco the error is always an integrity constraint error. The issue is that the sql is not queued and it runs at the same time throwing the error